# how can I customize lightdm theme?

Tags: lightdm

After I upgraded to 13.10 an ugly white icon theme appeared at top panel of lightdm, which does not fit bluish theme. I am using zorin greeter. I also tried gtk greeter but I didn't like it.

I took a pic of current lightdm theme using `lightdm --test-mode`
[image]

Above picture doesn't reflect actual appearance, icons full of white corners.

How can I replace my own icon sets with above icons?

EDIT: there is also no power button option at top right bar. Did latest lightdm drop some features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reference to myself in the future, I fixed it like that:

I switched to unity-greeter and run

```
sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter icon-theme-name ubuntu-mono-dark
```

And I have a nice icon set.

Comment: Sending a message to your future self never hurts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ubuntu Tweak, it has an option to set the lightdm gtk and icon theme.

To install it:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak

[image]

You'll find the options in the Tweaks sections (since changing themes for the login screen requires root privileges, you'll need to unblock it).

Also, in another section you can set the wallpaper (manually, or set it to use the same  your user has as default).

Comment: I applied your guide and rebooted. Unfortunately it didn't work.